# Size of Qt tableview

Tags: qt, qtableview

I am dynamically adding data to my tableview, but it would not exceed 10 rows. Is there a way that the tableView wraps around its contents?

For example, in the image below, there is so much extra space on the right and on the bottom. How could I get rid of that?

[image: QT TableView size]

Thanks.

Comment: For the space in the right, you can set the horizontal header stretch to take the space. Something like `table->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(2, QHeaderView::Stretch);`. 2 is the index of the last column.

Comment: `horizontalHeader` doesn't seem to have a method called `setResizeMode()`

Comment: Well, you probably use Qt5. Try `QHeaderView::setSectionResizeMode()` than.